# Frequently Getting the Error Message "too many requests"

Tags: cpanel, cloudflare, whm

Within the last 2 months the error message "too many requests" has started showing up for those using my site.

The site is hosted on a server with a 32 core CPU and 64 GB of RAM. The site usually only uses 10% of the CPU and 15% of the RAM.

I do not have Mod_Evasive installed on the server. In the my.cnf file I have max_connections set to 3000.

I recently changed the PHP-FPM Max Requests from 20 to 200 and this only seemed to make the error message appear more.

I do have all traffic going through CloudFlare, so as far as the server is concerned, all of the traffic is coming from CloudFlare IP addresses. I also use CloudFlare to cache front-end content to reduce the strain on the server.

Is there anything in cPanel/WHM that produces the error message "too many requests" besides Mod_Evasive?

cPanel/WHM Version:110.0.10
OS: CentOS v7.9.2009

Comment: "Too many requests" is usually a response from a rate limit configuration. That setting maybe part of your server, hosting company or CloudFlare settings. Another possible culprit is that Apache is not using the *KeepAlive On* configuration, and every visitor is creating different connections instead of reusing the existing ones.